# How does Web App refresh Google Login token in AWS serverless configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-oauth, serverless-framework

I have a React+Redux application which talks with AWS Resources (e.g. DynamoDB). To get access to DynamoDB:

1. Web App gets an access_token / id_token from Google, Facebook etc.
2. Web App exchanges Facebook / Google token to Cognito Federated Identities token.
3. With Federated Identities' token, Web App can talk with DynamoDB and other AWS resources using aws-sdk.

The problem is when Facebook / Google tokens expire (after 1-2 hours). Then I cannot refresh my Federated Identities token and I cannot talk with AWS resources.

**How to refresh Google token directly from Web App using Javascript?**

Google recommends to **NOT** to use and store refresh token in Web Application, but send access token (or id token) to the backend which exchanges it on refresh token. According to this, have I setup additional Lambda function (to exchange access token to refresh token with Google) and table in DynamoDB (where I store refresh token)?

**...or...**

Can I force to receive refresh token to Web Application and store in local storage?

Answer (score 0):

Store refresh token in local storage is not a good idea because user can see local storage in developer tools or can run Javascript function locally which fetch data from local storage on your site/webapp.

You can setup lambda function for this purpose and store refresh token in `HttpOnly` cookie. You can set response header from your lambda function (nodejs example):

```
response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'refresh_token="your_refresh_token"; HttpOnly');
```

This cookie will be sent on each request from your client to lambda.

`HttpOnly` will insure you that this cookie can't be accessible from javascript.